# Can I use TFT LCD and USB FS Mode at same time with STM32F429I

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

Hello everybody I am trying to make an STM USB HOST and taking some datas from keyboard and this data will show on LCD Panel. 
But somehow I can't set the pins by using CubeMX. The program gives error when I try to open TFT-LCD properties after I opened USB HOST Mode. The program says the two features use the same pins.
Is it possible to open same properies at the same time?

Comment: Have you checked the data sheet? Some peripherals can be mapped to other pins, some not. If both peripherals have to use the same pin, you can not use them at the same time. Try to find another controller where the peripherals are using different pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part numbers beginning with `STM32F429I` are in 176-pin packages that have enough pins to support both TFT and USB-FS at the same time. I've tried it in an empty project with a `STM32F429IET` MCU, the USB pins ended up on `PA11` and `PA12`, and the TFT pins are all over the place (layout designers just love it). Now trying to find out what can cause the conflict. Clicking on PA11 reveals that the pin *could* be configured to `LTDC_R4`, but this function is assigned to `PH10`. Click on `PA12`, it could be configured to `LTDC_R5`, but this function is mapped to `PH11`. Of course, if you have set `PH10` or `PH11` before to some other function, then you have a problem.

Now I have a feeling that you are *not designing hardware* but trying to do stuff on an existing board. In this case, you can't *define* the pinout. **Find the board schematics** in the documentation, then work from there, assigning functions to pins according to their intended function. Trace the connections from the USB socket to the MCU to find out which pins are connected to it, then use the **pin function mapping table in the datasheet** to find out *which* USB controller can talk to it. Then activate that interface in CubeMX, and **verify** that it got mapped to the right pins. If not, you can hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and drag it to the right place. Pin down the verified pins with the right mouse key, otherwise CubeMX will rearrange them at the hint of a conflict. When all pins are set, save a backup of the project as a baseline to return to when you start another software project on the same board.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me say one more thing here; I've implemented a driver in Full Speed mode and then tried to do same thing in High Speed mode at final stage the same code works in both cases. Thank you for answer